# What code to use in an array to call the current sub-category?

Tags: wp-query, categories, woocommerce-offtopic, array

On a page like taxonomy-product_cat.php - this function lists just the products for the called sub-category - bags:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'product_cat' => 'bags')
$loop = new WP_Query( $args ); while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
```

I can hardcode list all the sub-categories and then dynamically list the products.  I want to dynamically create the subcategory list with the associated products listed with it - what is the best way to do this?  I am thinking that if I make the 'product_cat' => dynamic - is a way to achieve this?

Comment: do you mean the actual category of the category archive page, or a sub-category of that actual category? in what file are you using that code?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using `WP_Query` at all. The [standard loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/#the-loop-in-detail) will automatically display the correct posts.

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

endwhile;
```

Comment: This lists all products of the current parent category.  There is no ordering into sub-category.  Maybe my question is not clear enough and I will rewrite it.  I am running a foreach loop that can list the subcategories, and I was looking for code to list that sub-categories products.  When I put your code it it lists all parent category items under each subcategory so does not really work for me. But it did help me advance in a few other issues - thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can use `get_queried_object()`, within that object you can get the `slug` or `id`.

Comment: If the correct category is the "queried object" (past tense), why would they query it again?